# UVs to XYZs python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of UV vertexes and the corresponding XYZ coordinates on the model.

So far I have this code:

```
import bpy

outfile = open('c:\\tmp\\temp.txt', 'w')

me = bpy.context.object.data
uv_layer = me.uv_layers.active.data

for poly in me.polygons:
    outfile.write( "\n")
    for li in poly.loop_indices:
        vi = me.loops[li].vertex_index
        uv = uv_layer[li].uv
        outfile.write("(%f,%f)" % ( uv.x, uv.y))

outfile.close()
```

What I need to work out is where the vertex data is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the vertex data in the `object.data` that you are using.

```
bpy.context.object.data.vertices[vi].co
```

Or each component -

```
bpy.context.object.data.vertices[vi].co.x
bpy.context.object.data.vertices[vi].co.y
bpy.context.object.data.vertices[vi].co.z
```